# How to break function execution after some time interval in PHP

Tags: php

I have php script for mail sending.First I get all record from Db and and send mail of each customer.

```
function perform_task() {
    // Record selection and ther stuff
    $status = mail();
    // update status
}

function mail() {
    // $mail is smtp mail object
    if ($mail->send()) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

see above perform_task function.First I get all records and for each record I call mail() function to send mail but due to smtp detail server problem I can't get any response from mail function and after 5 minute my script break and gives me fatal error, and I can't update status in DB.I want to handle this error.I want  to break mail function execution after 5 minute.If I get get any response from mail function then I want to update status fail.

Is there anytimeout function in PHP?

Comment: what is the `smtp detail server problem` you mention? Is the smtp server offline?

Comment: it doesn't matter what detail is. I just want that if I don't get ant response till 5 minute.function should be break and next  code should be executed

Comment: 1. the php scripts usually have a timeout when they are killed fro security reasons, though that can be configured. 2. every smtp client implementation does have a timeout setting, since it is a networking client. What type of client do you use? "smtp mail object" is a bit vague... There is absolutely no sense in waiting 5 minutes for a response. 10-20 Seconds should be more than enough.

Comment: You can do it using php `sleep` function...

Comment: I have hostgator smtp detail . I am using zend_mail for sending mail. Is there any option to set timeout in smtp configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I see some things in your code.

1.) You should rename your `mail` function to `sendMail` for example. When you use the same name as the internal function its very confusing.

2.) If you use a good library like Swiftmailer for example you get a short reply if the Email was send or you have an error and you can check that. The normal mail function do the same, too.

And the last thing is mail sending today is a complicated thing when you send a lot of E-Mail. You have to look to so many things for example that you don't send your E-Mails too fast to one provider otherwise you are blocked for example. If you have a lot of E-Mails you should have a timeout every 50 - 100 E-Mails for example. So iterate only over 100 E-Mail then wait for a few seconds and send again.

Otherwise you can get problems. You can work with `sleep` to wait after the iteration.

Swiftmailer has a function to limit the sending for example. There you can say how much the system should send in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
$ptime=time();  //current time before sending mail
$interval=5;    //interval in seconds
if(((time() - $ptime) <= $interval){
    //execute code here...
    perform_task();
}
```

Comment: ...then you can modify that into a loop!

Answer (score 0):

Usually php script should finish it's work in less then 2-3 seconds - the less the better, or it is decided as very slow. Slow things should run on the background, for example scheduled by cron. You can have script, that is executed every 5 minutes, and works 4:55. Scripts, executed in background do not have execution time limitations usually, they can work for hours, but shouldn't.

Another way for you - use some sort of flag, so when one copy of script is running, another exits if executed. And schedule the script to execute every minute.

Also there should be set timeout for mail function, maybe 30 sec. If it can not deliver email in 30 seconds, probably it is unable to deliver it at all.

For massive emails distribution it's better to use some sort of specialized service through their API.

Another way is to get VPS just for 5$/month, configure it for massive emails distribution. In this case you will have to pay for proper setup once and pay a little for hosting, maybe some more for support, so you\ll need to calculate, what is better for you.

That's the least that should be done if you want your emails to be delivered fast and in a proper way.